# LazyLoadingException on ElementCollection when no related objects

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql

I Have relation defined like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "recipe_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"))
@Column(name = "type")
@OrderColumn(name = "sort_order")
private List<String> types;
```

And I try to retreive it with JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM MealPlanWeekRecipe r " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.recipe " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.recipe.types " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.mealPlan " +
        "WHERE r.id.weekId = :week_id " +
        "AND r.id.mealPlanId IN :inclList")
LinkedHashSet<MealPlanWeekRecipe> findByIdWeekIdAndIdMealPlanIdInEagerly(
        @Param("week_id") Long weekId,
        @Param("inclList") Collection<Long> mealPlanIds);
```

Can someone explain me why I have LazyLoadingException when recipe does not have any type and I try to access it? Shouldn't it be null at least, or empty list?